# Spring boot using foreign key in crudRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities

- `CarWash` (`Wash` set)
- `Wash` (`car_wash_id` FK to `CarWash`)
- `WashComment`(`wash_id` FK to `Wash`)

Is there any way to write this query

```
   @Query(value="select * from wash_comment where wash_comment.wash_id=(select wash_id from wash where wash.car_wash_id=2", nativeQuery=true))
List<WashComment> findAllByCarWashId(CarWash carWash)
```

without using nativeQuery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**An advice to dealing with JPA**: look away from tables, columns, and all the RDBMS objects you have, and focus on the Entities, their properties and relations.

If I understood your problem correctly, you can let Spring Boot solve it automatically, by using a

```
List<WashComment> findByWash_CarWash_Id($Parameter(name="id") int id)
```

method signature - where the `_` has the meaning of the `.` between and their properties, a *traversal point* - to specify lookup based on `wash.carWash.id`. So this would translate to something like this:

```
select * 
from WashComment wc
where wc.wash.carWash.id=:id
```

(Which would of course be perfectly valid to put into the `@Query` annotation)

This assumes, your WashComment and Wash objects looks like this:

```
public class WashComment {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @OneToMany
  private Wash wash;

  //... left out for brevity
}

public class Wash {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @OneToMany
  private CarWash carWash;

  //... left out for brevity
}
```

And the `@Id` field of the `Wash` class is named `id`.

More information about this kind of expression here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

**Advice 2**: if you ever need to use an inner select - try to rewrite it with a `JOIN`. 99 times out of 100, it will be possible and that is a lot more readable, and usually significantly more performant:

```
select wc.* 
from wash_comment wc
join wash w on wc.wash_id=w.wash_id
where wash.car_wash_id=2
```

(Disclaimer: I can't try any of this now, no JRE anywhere near to play with...)